# How can I use this memory dependence predictor project in gem5?

Tags: gem5

How can I apply the code from the following project to gem5?

https://github.com/yuting-liu/Memory-Dependence-Predictor

Kndly give some instruction to help my problem ..

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

To download, compile and run gem5 you can follow the instructions on the official website: https://www.gem5.org/getting_started/

Regarding the memory dependence predictor project, as they say in their github page, "After downloading GEM5 system, please rename mem_load_pair/ and mem_store_set/ into mem/, to substitute src/mem/". However, it won't be that easy, since neither did they specificy what was the master commit from which they branched their code, nor did they use versioning when implementing their code. You **won't** be able to simply copy and paste their code into the current gem5 version, because it has changed a lot over the last years.

The ideal option if you want your research to have more realistic results is to port their code to the current version, but although I haven't checked their code, it will definitely be a hard task if you are not familiarized with gem5.

That being said, my best advice is to send them an e-mail requesting the commit from which they branched their gem5 version, download gem5, revert back to that commit and then substitute the "official" src/mem/ folder by their mem_load_pair/ and mem_store_set/ folders (renaming it to src/mem/).